# Yii2 render image in browser without image tag using yii2-imagine

Tags: yii2, php-imagine

I'm using yii2-imagine

```
$imagine = yii\imagine\Image::getImagine();
Imagine->open('path/watermark.jpg')->show('jpg');
```

My problem is it not show the image, it show that:

```
����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality ��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222����"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�
```

Any idea?

Comment: What are the headers?

Comment: How about this? `$imagine = new Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();`, then `$imagine->open('path/watermark.jpg')->show('jpg');`? I mean you just defined that `$imagine` variable but you didn't use it to open and show the image.

Comment: What do you mean? headers of the photo?

Comment: I cannot use new Imagine\Imagick\Imagine(); I get message Imagick is not installed

Comment: Try this as 2nd line `$imagine->open('path/watermark.jpg')->show('jpg');`, and keep your first line the same.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish actually do you want to eventually display that image inside the image tag? I can help out if that is the case.

Comment: Yes exactly, this solves the issue
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($imagine->getImagine()->open($source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `getImagine()` function first to invoke the `GD` or `Imagick` which ever available instance then call `->open()` and `->show()` on the object. Moreover, you need to provide the `$options` for the image to display too. You can copy paste the following code inside an action in your controller and can see the result image. I just tested on my local system, and it is in working, just remember to provide valid path to the `$source` variable

```
use yii\imagine\Image;    

$source="/path/to/your/image.jpg";        
$imagine = new Image();

$options = array(
            'resolution-units' => \Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH,
            'resolution-x' => 300,
            'resolution-y' => 300,
            'jpeg_quality' => 100,
        );

echo $imagine->getImagine()->open($source)->show('jpg',$options);
```

Apart from the above solution that displays the image in the browser if you want to display the image inside the `img` tag you can `base64_encode` the raw image data returned from the `open()` method and provide into the tag like below.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($imagine->getImagine()->open($source)).'" >';
```

Hope it helps